# How to select columns which have specific character?

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I have a table with 5 columns  dk_apple_1, pineapple_dk, egg_dk_one, ice_44, shift3. How can i select those column names which have characters dk?
So in result I select only first three columns of the dataset.

Comment: `data %>% select(contains("dk"))`

Comment: Base R: `data[grep("dk", names(data))]`.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `grepl` for a base R solution:

```
df[grepl("dk", names(df), fixed=TRUE)]
```

Note that the `fixed=TRUE` option just means that we don't really need to use the full regex engine, but instead just want an exact substring match.

Answer (score 1):

dplyr has the functionality to select the columns based on names. tidyr matches patterns in columns names, So using dplyr and tidyr package from tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
df<- df %>% 
  dplyr::select(tidyr::contains("dk"))
```

refer tidyverse [here](https://www.tidyverse.org/packages/)

Comment: Can you provide additional detail on why this is an appropriate solution? That will help future readers—if not the OP—better understand your thinking, and help reduce the need for follow-up questions.

Comment: @JeremyCaney I have updated my answer, hope this helps better. The preference to answers can be based on the end-user. My solution has package dependency which might not be preferred in all cases, as package dependency adds extra monitoring in the production environment, but it can have faster processing. So it's based on the requirement. For this problem, I personally prefer Tim and akrun's answer as they are from base R

Comment: How can you also select the ID column within this code? The ID column is called simply ID.

Answer (score 1):

An option. with `startsWith` from `base R`

```
df[startsWith(names(df), "dk")]
```